# For an old machine with 4 GB of RAM, is a 32-bit or 64-bit system faster?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

I installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04 for the first time, and I think it is heavier than the 32-bit version. While it was installing it got stuck. I tried four times to install.

Is it true that Ubuntu does not get very many updates? Does installing less software and updates help to keep the system running smoothly and fast?

My system has these specs:

- Intel-E5700 processor
- ASUS P5G41T-MLX3 motherboard
- 4 GB RAM

I know it is old and slow. My question is this:

Do I have to change it to 32-bit for my PC to work faster?

Comment: Hanging is generally more due to a bug or configuration issue, changing to 32bit may not fix those issues.

Comment: Your question is not well written, I don't understand the question about the one and only rule to run everything smooth and faster.

Comment: "the one and only rule to run everything smooth and faster" means dont touch anything that you don't know about  it.i was trying to be an engineer and soon my pc will stop working if i dont change my habbit of becoming charles babbage.hope you understand now.. @thomasrutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have enough RAM, 64-bit is preferred. But in some cases it is not true. For instance, I have an old laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo CPU T5450. It supports 64-bit operations. But it appeared that not very well. 32-bit systems run much better with this CPU. Technical details why this happens may be found in the net. But this is applicable only to some old cpu's where 64-bit operations were not made well yet.

Comment: yes, @pilot6 you are right.

Answer (score 4):

64bit is typically faster but does use slightly more RAM. If you are running into a situation where 64bit addressing is using up all your RAM, that could be an argument for using 32bit.

That said, 4GB of RAM is plenty for a typical desktop. Therefore the issue you are seeing is likely nothing to do with the architecture and probably something else (a wonky driver, hardware fault, etc).

And *that* said, trying 32bit might not hurt. It's monetarily free and the only real cost is the time it takes to download and install. There's no other way to switch between architectures.

Comment: You don't even need to install, you can try from LiveCD/USB.

Comment: thanks a lot friend for telling me that 4gb ram is enough for a 64bit os. (y)

Comment: NGRhodes i know,no need to install,,it is working from usb good..but i am afraid of future,,if something will go wrong,,i have no cd,dvd writer for installing any os and sometimes usb sticks dont help.

Answer (score 0):

Having very similar system specs (P5G41M, E5300, 4GB RAM, 1GB GT610 card, 25GB swap partition) I have found that, especially when used for gaming, the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 15.04 runs a bit smoother than the 64-bit, but this is just based on personal observation.

When it comes to updates and drive space, yes, the less you clutter up your hard drive the more efficient your system will be. I have a 500GB hard drive with about 195GB free and am considering upping my storage to 1TB+ in the near future for that reason. Keep in mind, though, that updates are meant not only for feature additions but more often than not are bug fixes which will also help your system run more smoothly.

Comment: yes less you clutter more your system will feel great :-D ,,i think buying more storage devices is not too good idea,if you want to buy ,,buy a ssd and make your 500 gb hdd a secondry storage device.yes,updates are not meant only for new features ,,that is why for now on ,,i install only some updates.and the last thing,,next time dont waste your money on a gpu else buy a cpu which have integrated gpu or buy a motherboard with integrated graphics in it.

Answer (score -5):

First of all 64-bit is not like 32-bit at all:

- The 64-bit version is faster and reads all the existing RAM in your computer, ensuring you can use it all.
- The 32-bit version is not as fast. It reads only up to 3.2 GB of RAM in your computer. So even if you have more it won't be used.

[What is difference between 32 bit and 64 bit](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001498.htm)

#### About why your PC runs slow:

You may consider your PC not that powerful. So you might want to try Lubuntu or Elementary OS, for example. Such a lightweight derivative will be easier for your PC to run. In particular, they don't feature such a heavy graphical interface, so you don't need as good of a graphics card.

Comment: That is not true about RAM.

Comment: how comes ? can u explain plz

Comment: ok,,@mohamed salah thanks  a lot..i will see for lubuntu (y).. Pilot6 ok,now i know it is not  related to ram or 32bit or 64 bit.

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001498.htm
can u see this one plz

Comment: Read about PAE. All modern Ubuntu releases use PAE.